# Populate select option value in Javascript and Materialize

Tags: javascript, materialize

Good evening, I would like to better understand how a form select should be set up using materialize. I have a modal with a form select option inside it.
As an option I want you to load me the values ​​of a myDoms list.
The code I use is this:

```
<div id = "insert" class = "modal">
      <div class = "modal-content">
    <div id = "insert">
  <FORM id = "finsert" action = "javascript: sendInsert ('finsert');">
       <div class = "row" id = "master_list">
      <h4> Add data </h4>
     
      <SELECT id = "domain"> <option> No domain </option> </SELECT>
       </ Div>
  </ Div>
```

the domain id is the vector that contains the list of domains and loads correctly if I don't use materialize.

With materialize I inserted in the head:

```
<Script>
         $ (document) .ready (function () {
            $ ( 'Select'). Material_select ();
                  });
      </ Script>
```

Unfortunately I don't load the list.

This is the correct way without materialize:

```
<div id = "insert" class = "c2 i1">
    <FORM id = "finsert" action = "javascript: sendInsert ('finsert');">
    
    <SELECT id = "domain"><OPTION> NO-DOMAIN </ OPTION>
    </ SELECT>
    </ TH>
    </ TR>
```

Surely I'm wrong to use the materialize right?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:**

Load jQuery and Materialize correctly, in the right order, before the closing body tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection"/>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    </head>

    <body>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

**Step 2:**

Place the component using the correct markup:

```
<div class="input-field col s12">
    <select>
      <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
      <option value="1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="2">Option 2</option>
      <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
    <label>Materialize Select</label>
  </div>
```

**Step 3:**

Run the initialisation as the last step:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('select');
    var instances = M.FormSelect.init(elems);
  });

  // Or with jQuery

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('select').formSelect();
  });
```

https://materializecss.com/getting-started.html

https://materializecss.com/select.html